# Use Closure Library inside Chrome DevTools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, google-closure, google-closure-library

I've checked out the Closure library [as instructred](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/gettingstarted), but can't find a way to use the library (i.e. goog.require('math') inside the Console just for trying it out and testing purposes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once Closure Library's [base.js](http://code.google.com/p/closure-library/source/browse/trunk/closure/goog/base.js) is loaded, you can reference the library in the Chrome Dev Tools console.

#### closure-test.html (load base.js)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Closure Library Test</title>
  <script src="http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/base.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Closure Library Test</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

#### Chrome Dev Tools Console

```
> goog.require('goog.math');
<* undefined
```

Observing `Resources | Frames | (closure-test.html) | Scripts`, math.js will be loaded.

```
> goog.math.modulo(-1, 8);
<* 7
```

Comment: Thanks! did so, but now I'm getting 
goog.require could not find: math